# Stumped on SQL Server 2008 R2 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with Classic ASP on Windows Server 2008 R2/IIS. I know classic ASP is pretty long in the tooth but it works fine with the stored procedures I am using. I have a stored procedure that does a simple update on a `smalldatetime` column, but I am now trying to make this procedure a dynamic one using a variable table name.

The standard procedure that works fine is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spendemerg]
(
  @rfid int
)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   Update EmergencyContent 
   Set content_expiry = DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE())
   Where content_id = @rfid
END
```

I am passing the variable parameter `@rfid` using ADO and it works fine. When I tried to change the procedure to use dynamic SQL to pass the table name as a variable, that's when I got into trouble.

This is the dynamic procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spendBroadcast]
    @rfid int,
    @strTable varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @strTable + 
               ' SET content_expiry = '''+ CONVERT(datetime,(DATEADD(minute, -10, GETDATE())), 121) +
               ''' WHERE content_id = '+ @rfid
    EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

The code runs ok in a query editor using the SQL management studio, but when executed via IIS/CLassic ASP, it fails with the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

when executing the stored procedure.

This is the ASP code:

```
Set objCm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objRe = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  objCm.ActiveConnection = objConn
  objCm.CommandText = "spendBroadcast"
  objCm.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc


Set objParam = objCm.CreateParameter("rfid",adInteger,adParamInput,4, strID)
  objCm.Parameters.Append objParam
Set objParam = objCm.CreateParameter("strTable",adVarChar,adParamInput,100, strTableName)
 objCm.Parameters.Append objParam

Set objRe = objCm.Execute
```

Any thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated... thanks!

Comment: Since you are concatenating the date to a string, you need to convert it to a varchar to avoid the error. Or you need to pass the parameter into the string.

Comment: Why are you converting datetime to datetime in your dynamic sql? Original procedure just performs update. Any reason?

Comment: Why not just: `= 'UPDATE ' + @strTable + ' SET content_expiry = DATEADD(minute,-10,GETDATE()) WHERE content_id = '+ @rfid`

Comment: Thanks all... I tried using just:

Comment: Alex K's suggestion but received this error: > Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UPDATE EmergencyContent SET content_expiry = DATEADD(minute,-10,GETDATE()) WHERE content_id = ' to data type int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are building a dynamic SQL string then everything should be the same datatype (notice the 2 added conversions below):

```
SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @strTable + ' SET content_expiry = '''
            + cast(CONVERT(datetime,(DATEADD(minute,-10,GETDATE())),121) as nvarchar(100))
            +''' WHERE content_id = ' + cast(@rfid as nvarchar(100))
```

Comment: Thanks Eduard, I tried that and although it did not throw any errors, it also did not update the smalldatetime field, so I am wondering if the @rfid parameter was mis-interpreted. It is an Integer field. Thanks.